# selectedIndex is undefined with jQuery in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I have an ASP.NET dropdownlist like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMyDropDown" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Please pick one</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>option1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>option2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>option3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>option4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

A `CustomValidator` is bound to it, to see if the user chose an option. It calls the following javascript/JQuery function:

```
function checkValueSelected(sender, args) {
        var index = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMyDropDown").selectedIndex;
        args.IsValid = index > 0;
    }
```

but index is `undefined` when debugging with Firebug. The JQuery selector finds `select#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMyDropDown`, so that's **not** the problem. Does the `selectedIndex` property not exist?

On the internet I found examples that do almost exactly the same and it works. I'm quite lost on this one...

## Update

This is what Firebug shows:

[image: inspect]

As you can see, the `control` variable is some sort of array, with one entry which is actually what I want to be in `control`. I don't think JQuery's ID selector returns multiple values?

Comment: Can you use asp.net property to check this?

Comment: @sarwar026 I found out what's wrong, going to edit question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`selectedIndex` is not there ...

you should use `prop` of jquery...

```
var index = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMyDropDown").prop('selectedIndex');
```

or

```
 var index = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlMyDropDown").get(0).selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just read that `$("#id")` is NOT the same as `document.getElementById("id").`

Comment: See the comments [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Apparantly it is not the same, see my Firebug screenshot. The id selector returns an array, it will return a DOM element if done by `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester jQuery ALWAYS work with arrays . even if you think you have 1 id , some other guy can set multiple same id's (bad practice) - but still jquery  will be able to work with them. ( the first one IMHO)

Comment: And that's what I didn't know. I'm new to it, see. Strange that the ID selector does so too, since everyone would always append `.get(0)`...